# yii2 mailer smtp connection refused

Tags: email, yii2, smtp, mailer

When setting up my smtp mailer in the config file, it works fine. But if I manually create the SMPT mailer it fails (Connection refused). Can anybody assist?

Yii2 config file:

```
'components'=[
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
                'username' => 'email@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'password',
                'port' => '587', 
                'encryption' => 'tls', 
            ],
```

The following code in my controller does not work:

```
$mailer = new \yii\swiftmailer\Mailer();
$mailer->transport = new \Swift_SmtpTransport();
$mailer->transport
    ->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')
    ->setPort(587)
    ->setEncryption('tls');
$mailer->transport->setUsername('email@gmail.com');
$mailer->transport->setPassword('password');
```

and I receive an error message: Connection refused #111

I have tried port 465 on ssl and I receive the same message.

My main reason for doing this is that I have different client accounts, each of which has its own smtp. I therefore need one account per client and I cannot seem to do that via the config file.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: you do not need to create $mailer object. once configuration is set as you have done, you use email yii2 function, it shall set mail.

Comment: @RajeshPradhan thank you - but I need three different configurations (one for each SMTP account). How do I do that?

Comment: check this link.https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2723 they say create new mailer component, for example, mailer2 now call Yii::$app->mailer2->compose()...now malier2 will have different config. let me know if I have answer you question

Comment: @RajeshPradhan I tried this already but I get "mailer2 not found". There was another post with a similar idea. Maybe I am doing something wrong but when I add a custom parameter to web.php Yii::$app->custom always returns not found. If I could solve this problem, then everything will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it worked for me, I did as follow

```
'components'=[
    'mailer' => [  //Your default mailer
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
            'username' => 'email@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '587', 
            'encryption' => 'tls', 
        ],
    ],
'mailer2' => [  //Your custom mailer
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
            'username' => 'new_email@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'new_password',
            'port' => 'new_port587', 
            'encryption' => 'new_tls', 
        ],
    ]
```

following is for default config

```
 Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('info@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('xxx@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('Subject')
        ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
        ->setHtmlBody("Hello")
        ->send();
```

following with custom mailer config

```
 Yii::$app->mailer2->compose()
        ->setFrom('info@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('xxx@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('Subject')
        ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
        ->setHtmlBody("Hello")
        ->send();
```

create a component is the fastest solution, otherwise, you can use the parameter to store configuration, and call when needed.

Comment: Thank you so much Rajesh. Reading your post, I realise I made a really simple mistake! I have copied your approach and it works great. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to hear this.